# Can I use default values in a JSON decoder?

Tags: elm

I make a JSON request to a web API about books. My responses *usually* look like

```
{
    "status": "successful",
    "author": "Roald Dahl",
    "title": "Charlie and the Chocolate Factory"
}
```

So I decode it to a `Book` type using the author and title fields.

But sometimes, the requested book won't be in the database, so my response is just

```
{
    "status": "failed"
}
```

In this case I'd still look to return a `Book` type, but with the author and title set to "NOT FOUND".

I'm reading the JSON documentation, but I'm not sure if anything there is helpful to me or if I can even do this in Elm in a simple way. Would appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use `Json.Decode.oneOf` and add `Json.Decode.succeed "NOT FOUND"`as the last option OR, better use `Json.Decode.andThen`, first decode the status and then produce a `Maybe Book` (`Just Book` if status is successful and `Nothing` if it failed)

If there are more than one way it can fail, you could use `Result` instead of `Maybe`.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the `optional` function at Evan's [Json.Decode.Pipeline](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-decode-pipeline/3.0.0/Json-Decode-Pipeline#optional).

Then you can write it like this:

```elm
type alias User =
  { id : Int
  , name : String
  , email : String
  }


userDecoder : Decoder User
userDecoder =
  decode User
    |> required "id" int
    |> optional "name" string "blah"
    |> required "email" string
```

If you need to distinguish missing values and `null` values, this example is offered in the docs:

```elm
userDecoder2 =
    decode User
        |> required "id" int
        |> optional "name" (oneOf [ string, null "NULL" ]) "MISSING"
        |> required "email" string
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Json.Decode.oneOf`.
Just write decoder for both of the case and let `oneOf` combine them.

**edit to respond with the comment**

Using `oneOf` is the general way to handle handling multiple
possibilities.
But, here is the example code that I would code according to the requirement you've given.

```
type Book
    = Book
        { author : String
        , title : String
        }


fallBackBook =
    Book
        { author = "NOT FOUND"
        , title = "NOT FOUND"
        }


decode : String -> Book
decode str =
    let
        decoder =
            Json.map3 (,,)
                (Json.field "status" Json.string)
                (Json.field "author" Json.string)
                (Json.field "title" Json.string)
    in
        case Json.decodeString decoder str of
            Ok ( "successful", author, title ) ->
                Book { author = author, title = title }

            _ ->
                fallBackBook
```

Or, you can create another value `NotFound` which represents
"Book was not found" state.  This is the Elm way, I believe and recommend.

```
type Book
    = Book
        { author : String
        , title : String
        }
    | NotFound


bookDecoder : Json.Decoder Book
bookDecoder =
    Json.map2 (\x y -> Book { author = x, title = y })
        (Json.field "author" Json.string)
        (Json.field "title" Json.string)


decode : String -> Book
decode str =
    Json.decodeString bookDecoder str
        |> Result.withDefault NotFound
```

Comment: How would the default values be specified in one the decoder that needs them? Could your answer please show the two decoders, perhaps implemented using Json.Decode.map3?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would suggest that your author and title would be of `Maybe String` type. And "NOT FOUND" would be a display choice in case of `Nothing`. So it would be something like:

```elm
type Book =
    { status: String
    , author: Maybe String
    , title: Maybe String
    }

...

loadSuccessDecoder : Json.Decode.Decoder Book
loadSuccessDecoder =
    Json.Decode.map3 Book
        ( Json.Decode.field "status" Json.Decode.String )
        ( Json.Decode.maybe ( Json.Decode.field "author" Json.Decode.string ) )
        ( Json.Decode.maybe ( Json.Decode.field "title" Json.Decode.string ) )
```

Everything else, I think, should be a display choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can partially decode the response and check the status, and then decode further based on the value of status.

```
type alias Book =
    { title : String
    , author : String
    }


decodeBook : Decode.Decoder Book
decodeBook =
    Decode.field "status" Decode.string
        |> Decode.andThen
            (\status ->
                case status of
                    "successful" ->
                        Decode.map2 Book
                            (Decode.field "title" Decode.string)
                            (Decode.field "author" Decode.string)

                    _ ->
                        Decode.succeed (Book "NOT FOUND" "NOT FOUND")
            )
```

The decoder above first decodes the string from the field `status`. Then, if the status matches the string `"successful"`, it decodes the other 2 fields from the response. If the status is anything else, it creates a book with the title and author of `"NOT FOUND"`.